# Jprofiler do not detach on application crash

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jvm, jprofiler

I use java application with spring boot in docker.
Recently application start to consume more than 100% of CPU.
As we run it on AWS, the docker supervisor kills the container in few moments.

I setup Jprofiler agent to track the application. But after application is crashed I can't collect any data to analyse, because Jprofiler is detached, and all information is cleaned from JProfiler GUI.

Is it possible for Jprofiler GUI to not detach on application crash?

Jprofiler version is 10.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the recorded profiling data lives in the agent which runs in the profiled JVM. The JProfiler UI only gets partial aggregated versions of that data on demand. When the profiled JVM crashes, the source of the displayed data is lost.

Comment: Thats a pity. Do you know is there a way to retrieve profiling data from crashed container to connect somehow to them?

Comment: The data is in memory, after a crash it's gone.